# Item Click on Gridview with custom adapter and layout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, xamarin

I have a custom layout for my `grid`

grid.xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

row_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#35000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

now when I don't have the horizontal scroll view click event works fine, but when I add the horizontal scroll view it wont have any click event

I know if `grid` layout has any clickable child then the item click wont be handled, hence my question..

Is it possible to have both `horizontalscroll` and item click??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the image button takes focus when you click on item. so try adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the root element in layout –
in the row item layout. It worked for me.